# Changing the filter header in Kibana?

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

Is it possible to change the header name of the `filters` which displays after creating a `data table` or show a customized content rather than showing the whole query in the table?

Snapshot of how the `data table` looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can change the name of the query after adding a filter.

To do so, kindly click on the [Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nwmh.png) beside the Close Icon.
Upon clicking, you can enter the name for that filter which provides a textboxbelow the filter query box.